# Sending JSON data from raspberry pi to Bluemix MQTT broker

Tags: json, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, mqtt, ibm-cloud

I have been looking all around on how to send data as JSON objects over to the  IBM Bluemix broker using paho python from raspberry pi ....can anyone pls help

Comment: Please supply a little bit more detail of exactly what you are trying to do. I'm going yo guess that you are trying to send data to the IOT service, but this is not clear from your question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to use the IOT service then I suggest you look at this:

https://developer.ibm.com/iot/recipes/raspberry-pi/

Comment: Sorry for if i was unclear .Here is the link that i have been using as the reference                                                                                                        http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-mqtt-bluemix-iot-node-red-app/index.html                                                                               The link explains how to connect to the IOT service and publish event data in JSON using the MQTT protocol.The language used is JAVA.           I want to know how the  above can be done using python.

Comment: Pls can u help @hardillb